# Web Service return type complex object type

Tags: web-services

I have a web service which returns complex type as below:

```
<xs:complexType name="EmReturnValues">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="AdcTransactionNo" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CbsTransactionDate" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="CbsTransactionNo" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="IsInterBranchTransaction" type="xs:int"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="RelevantMessage" nillable="true" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="SucessBit" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Am able to get the response in object but how do I fetch individual values of the object ?

Tried accessing by objectName.AdcTransactionNo but failed.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean, "failed"? See http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/05/17/how-to-consume-a-web-service/

Comment: error: cannot find symbol objectName.AdcTransactionNo

Comment: And, maybe show how you created `objectName`?

Comment: It's the response object created for the Method call. Save the method call is callHelloWorld(); .. then Object objectName = (Object) port.callHelloWorld();

Comment: Why are you casting to `(Object)`?